# Regex para selecionar apenas um número dentro de determinadas Strings

Tags: java, regex

Eu tenho um log multi-line que gera múltiplos eventos, no entanto eu preciso tirar os `.` e pegar apenas as informações que estão antes dos "ms", ou seja "509833", "780414", etc.

```
2020-04-23 15:21:10,602 INFO  ecp-1-2089600 25000 Execution Info
+[Job_TransformGIM].............................................................509833 ms. Invocations 1
|-- [INIT]........................................................................2297 ms. Invocations 1
|--+[RUN].......................................................................507380 ms. Invocations 1
   |-- [AGENTtoRESOURCE]...........................................................125 ms. Invocations 1
   |-- [SCRIPTtoRESOURCE]..........................................................172 ms. Invocations 1
2020-04-23 15:40:38,347 INFO  ecp-1-2089600 25000 Execution Info
+[Job_TransformGIM].............................................................285409 ms. Invocations 1
|-- [INIT]........................................................................1875 ms. Invocations 1
|--+[RUN].......................................................................283362 ms. Invocations 1
   |-- [AGENTtoRESOURCE]............................................................93 ms. Invocations 1
   |-- [SCRIPTtoRESOURCE]...........................................................93 ms. Invocations 1
   |-- [ENDPOINTtoRESOURCE].........................................................78 ms. Invocations 1
   |-- [SWITCHtoRESOURCE]...........................................................78 ms. Invocations 1
2020-04-23 15:21:10,602 INFO  ecp-1-2089600 25000 Execution Info
+[Job_TransformGIM]...........................................................54509833 ms. Invocations 1
|-- [INIT]........................................................................2297 ms. Invocations 1
|--+[RUN].......................................................................507380 ms. Invocations 1
   |-- [AGENTtoRESOURCE]...........................................................125 ms. Invocations 1
```

Eu montei a seguinte regex, mas creio que tenha uma forma melhor de fazer isso:

```
^\d+\-\d+\-\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\-\d+\-\d+\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\+\[\w+_\w+\]\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.(?P<teste>\d+\s+)
```

Comment: Corrigido, a aplicação é multi-line feita em Java, mas preciso pegar apenas o valor que está na linha Job_TransformGIM, ou seja "509833", "285409". São logs gigantescos, então gera um evento como este a cada minuto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma alternativa é `\[\w+\]\.+(\d+)\s+ms\.`.

Como o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` já pega letras, dígitos e também o caractere `_`, não precisa fazer `\w+_\w+` (na verdade desse jeito obriga a ter um `_`, já usando apenas `\w+` ele aceita também os casos que tem apenas letras - a menos que a intenção seja de fato pegar os nomes que tem pelo menos um `_`, claro).

Para os pontos, usei `\.+` ([uma ou mais ocorrências](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) do caractere `.`), já que a quantidade pode variar e você não tem como saber a quantidade exata (até porque o valor do número que vem depois influencia na quantidade de pontos, então fiz assim que é mais simples e parece contemplar todos os casos).

Depois eu pego os números (`\d+`), seguido de um ou mais espaços (`\s+`), seguido de `ms.`. Os números estão entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), assim consigo pegar o valor deles posteriormente. Você tinha usado um grupo nomeado (`(?P<teste>`), mas não achei necessário ter um nome, pois a regex só possui um grupo e posso me referir a ele pela numeração (como é o primeiro par de parênteses da regex, então é o grupo 1).

> *Sem contar que a sintaxe `(?P<teste>` é inválida em Java. [Grupos nomeados possuem uma variação de sintaxe entre as linguagens](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html), e [segundo a documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special), em Java seria apenas `(?<teste>`.*

Enfim, assumindo que todo o texto está em uma string, ficaria assim:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

...
String texto = "2020-04-23 15:21:10,602 INFO  ecp-1-2089600 25000 Execution Info\n"
                + "+[Job_TransformGIM].............................................................509833 ms. Invocations 1\n"
                + "|-- [INIT]........................................................................2297 ms. Invocations 1\n"
                + "|--+[RUN].......................................................................507380 ms. Invocations 1\n"
                + "   |-- [AGENTtoRESOURCE]...........................................................125 ms. Invocations 1\n"
                + "   |-- [SCRIPTtoRESOURCE]..........................................................172 ms. Invocations 1\n"
                + "2020-04-23 15:40:38,347 INFO  ecp-1-2089600 25000 Execution Info\n"
                + "+[Job_TransformGIM].............................................................285409 ms. Invocations 1\n"
                + "|-- [INIT]........................................................................1875 ms. Invocations 1\n"
                + "|--+[RUN].......................................................................283362 ms. Invocations 1\n"
                + "   |-- [AGENTtoRESOURCE]............................................................93 ms. Invocations 1\n"
                + "   |-- [SCRIPTtoRESOURCE]...........................................................93 ms. Invocations 1\n"
                + "   |-- [ENDPOINTtoRESOURCE].........................................................78 ms. Invocations 1\n"
                + "   |-- [SWITCHtoRESOURCE]...........................................................78 ms. Invocations 1\n"
                + "2020-04-23 15:21:10,602 INFO  ecp-1-2089600 25000 Execution Info\n"
                + "+[Job_TransformGIM]...........................................................54509833 ms. Invocations 1\n"
                + "|-- [INIT]........................................................................2297 ms. Invocations 1\n"
                + "|--+[RUN].......................................................................507380 ms. Invocations 1\n"
                + "   |-- [AGENTtoRESOURCE]...........................................................125 ms. Invocations 1";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\[\\w+\\]\\.+(\\d+)\\s+ms\\.").matcher(texto);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // pegar o grupo 1
}
```

Repare que, por estar dentro de uma string, o caractere `\` deve ser escrito como `\\`.

O [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) vai percorrendo a string procurando por ocorrências da regex. Quando encontra, basta pegar o grupo 1, que contém os números desejados. A saída é:

```
509833
2297
507380
125
172
285409
1875
283362
93
93
78
78
54509833
2297
507380
125
```

Agora, se você está processando o arquivo linha a linha, pode fazer assim:

```
String[] linhas = // linhas do arquivo
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\[\\w+\\]\\.+(\\d+)\\s+ms\\.").matcher("");
for (String linha : linhas) {
    if (matcher.reset(linha).find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Assumindo que cada linha só tem uma ocorrência do valor em milissegundos. Se uma linha puder ter mais de uma ocorrência, troque o `if` por um `while`.

---

Se quiser transformar o valor em um número, basta fazer:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    int ms = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    // usar o valor de ms para o que você precisar
}
```

Ou, caso tenha valores acima de 2.147.483.647 (que é o [valor máximo que um `int` suporta](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE)):

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    long ms = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Um `long` suporta valores até [9.223.372.036.854.775.807](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE). Como suas saídas referem-se a durações de execução, dificilmente ultrapassará este valor (já que essa quantidade de milissegundos corresponde a mais de 290 milhões de anos).

---

Se você tiver "certeza absoluta" que a sequência "números ms." não ocorre em nenhum outro lugar do arquivo (somente nos lugares que você quer pegar), pode simplificar a regex para `"(\\d+)\\s+ms\\."` (ou ainda `"(\\d+) ms\\."`, se sempre tiver apenas um espaço entre o número e o texto "ms."). O restante do código é o mesmo.